# Find "command not found" when executed in bash loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, command-line, find

I'm trying to write a bash script to generate lists of files. I figured I'd simply call 'find' within a loop. Unfortunately it generated a "find: command not found" error when in the loop and I don't know why.

To keep things short, this cut-down version replicates the issue without bogging us down in irrelevant code.

```
#!/bin/bash
IFSprev=$IFS
IFS=$'|'
PATHS='openvpn|vms'
SOURCE='/mnt/store/'

#find "${SOURCE}vms" -type f
for PATH in ${PATHS}
do
   echo -----------------------------------
   find "${SOURCE}${PATH}" -type f
done
IFS=$IFSprev
```

While troubleshooting, I added the first 'find' command... with that added, it subsequently works within the loop. If I comment it out again, the 'find' in the loop reverts to throwing the error.

Given I'm gonna be redirecting the loop output to a file, I can live with the extra 'find' command or even just redirect to null. However, I'm an inquisitive kinda guy and I really want to find what the problem is.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Use lower-case names for your own variables to avoid overwriting variables with meaning to the operating system or shell -- like you just did here. See [the relevant POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) indicating that all-caps names are used for built-in variables and environment variables with meaning to the shell and operating system, and that the namespace of variables with at least one lower-case character is reserved for application use.

Comment: That said -- if you want to iterate over a list of things, you should be using an actual array, not setting IFS and then splitting a string as if it were an array. `paths=( openvpn vms ); for path in "${paths[@]}"; do echo "processing $path"; done`

Comment: Thanks Charles. Reasonably new to Linux and I'd read some other pages that suggested using caps for variables for ease of readability, but now it's pointed out to me I totally understand. I'd also tried arrays but had some problems when paths contained spaces and subsequent inclusion/exclusion of quotes causing doubling up, but now I have this non-issue resolved, I'll go back and take another look why my array is goosed.

Comment: Not sure why my question got down voted. It was a noob mistake, but it was a genuine one. Anyone suggest what I've done wrong here?

Comment: Can't speak to the downvote -- but typically something that's genuinely a bad question will get more than one of them, or be closed, or get some more useful comments about *why* it's bad with links to the help center; I wouldn't sweat just one.

Comment: (not that I mean to imply that all closed questions are bad questions -- for example, if someone asks something that's a duplicate in a different enough way that it provides a new set of search terms that can be used to find a preexisting, more canonical question and answer, then a question closed-as-duplicate can be a very useful addition to the knowledgebase; it's intentional that closed dupes can still be upvoted).

Comment: Re: finding advice that conflicts with POSIX -- unfortunately, there's a lot of cargo-culting floating around the shell world -- even some references with lots of Google juice are prone. I'd suggest the [Wooledge BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) and the [bash-hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/) as two resources that tend to be reliable and consistent. (There are some places where best practices are in dispute -- `set -e` is a prime example -- but a good resource will show both sides, or at least link to another, when multiple respected, defensible options exist).

Comment: That's brilliant info. Thanks Charles, vastly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's looking for `find` in `$PATH`... which your script has destroyed.

Comment: You're not wrong... what a moron.

It was the fact the first 'find' makes the second work that meant i completely overlooked the fact I was trashing my $PATH

Thanks!